# Rails assets load from the wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just finished writing controller for a project, everything works fine on my local computer, but in production images from the view of my controller load from 'images/bg/*' instead of 'assets/bg', same goes for javascripts ('javascripts/games/' instead of 'assets/games/')
I think the reason behind this is because image_tag somehow generates wrong links, but what's with javascripts? I don't know what to do

The server computer runs nginx, if it matters

See for yourself - this is my controller http://gorodigr.com/ruletka , and this is another one   http://gorodigr.com/poker_kosti as an example

[image]

application.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require  websocket_rails/main
//= //require jquery_ujs

//= //require bootstrap-alert
//= //require vallenato
//= //require websocket_rails/main
//= //require_tree .

//= require turbolinks


jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
.
.
.
some javascript
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require main

 */
```

**Update**

Now it behaves even more strangely, same image_tag path, different results
[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/U9R22e4.png here is a screenshot if you don't want to go to suspicious links

Comment: Are you not getting images from the assets folder in your development environment ? I mean, can you check if the development environment fetches assets from the assets folder ?

Comment: No, in development (on my local machine) everything works fine

Comment: If all your assets are being fetched from assets folder in your development environment than I dont see any reasons as to why this would be behaving differently on production, moreover your assets are not precompiled, so I suspect there's something wrong with the way you're calling these files. Can you paste application.js code in here ?

Comment: My assets are precompiled

Comment: If the assets are precompiled, you wouldn't see so many js and css files, instead you would see only `application-hashcode.js` and `application-hashcode.css`. So would be better if you paste you application.js and application.css code to further inspect what your doing.

Comment: You can reach the right js, if you go to http://gorodigr.com/assets/games/ruletka.js, everything that I want to know is why the view generates wrong link to http://gorodigr.com/javascripts/games/ruletka.js

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the assets are loading from the "wrong" place - they are likely subject to the workings of the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), especially if you're seeing problems in `production`

--

**Asset Pipeline**

The main issue you have is likely to do with the asset pipeline. Let me explain

The asset pipeline is a feature of Rails, removed in Rails 4 actually (but the functionality still persists), whereby your "assets" (`images`, `css` and `javascripts`) will be kept in a set of folders detatched from your "views". You'll then be able to call these as you wish

The magic of the asset pipeline is that when you run your app in production, it will take your files, compile them, and pull them from a totally different location (`public/assets`), a path which will be called by your [`asset path helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html):

--

**Structure**

Bottom line is that if you have to concern yourself with the path of your assets, you're not doing it right.

As long as you keep your assets in the correct folders & use the helpers, your app should serve them correctly. In regards to your specific issue, let's look at what the problem might be:

Your assets *should* be stored as such:

```
-- app
-- | assets
-- | -- | javascripts
-- | -- | -- application.js
-- | -- | -- your.js
-- | -- | -- other.js
-- | -- | -- javascripts.js
```

This will give you the ability to call any of these files using the different asset path helpers you are provided with:

```
#app/views/layouts/index.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "your", "other", "javascripts" %>
```

In conjunction with this, you'll want to consider the role of [manifest directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) in your assets:

```
#app/assets/javascriots/application.js
// ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

This means that if you call the `application.js` file in your layout in development, it will just load the files you need. If you load its [precompiled version](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) in production, it will concatenate all the required files into the single `application.js` file

--

**Fix**

In light of your image & updated post, here's what I'd do:

> 1. Put all your javascripts into the correct folder (`/assets/javascripts`)
> 2. "Require" all the files you need in your application.js
> 3. If you want to include separate files, precompile it separately

Firstly, put all your files into the `app/assets/javascripts` folder

Secondly, fix the following problems in your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require bootstrap-alert
//= require vallenato
//= require websocket_rails/main
//= require_tree .
```

Thirdly, if you want to include `/games/ruletka.js`, you'll be best doing this:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ['games/raletka.js']

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "games/raletka" %>
```

Comment: There are 9 .js.coffee files in /assets/javascripts, and all of them including mine are in config.assets.precompile. I'm not going to change  anything in application.js because each .js.coffee file except mine works like it should. I have "javascript_include_tag "games/#{action_name}"" in application.html.haml and action_name is defined

Comment: You've sent me an image. I can't see what's happening - you'll need to tell me if it's working or not

Comment: You can see on that image that the path for javascript is right - 'assets' not 'javascripts', and that is another controller, not mine. With the same setup only my controller works differently

Comment: Okay - does the file load? If not, you have a problem; if so, then there's no issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different assets than application.js you have to include them in the config for precompile.

For example in your config/environments/production.rb uncomment the following line and adjust it to your assets.

```
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile += %w( games/ruletka.js )
```

Images should be automatically precompiled, so they should work out of the box. But for CSS you have to use special helper to get correct url:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

For more details, reffer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Also, if you're deploying with capistrano, make sure to include 'capistrano-rails' gem, and enable it to allow precompilation of the assets after your deployment is finished.

Comment: I did add ruletka.js to config.assets.precompile, and the did assets:precompile, but no luck. I don't know what capistrano is, but I have it in Gemfile, I'm going to add capistrano-rails, but how do I enable precompilation in it? thanks for the response.

Comment: Do you deploy with capistrano? If so, the assets:precompile will be triggered on your production server after your deployment.

Comment: I can run it manually with 'RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile". What's the difference?